# How can I add a constraint to attach two view together programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to get my UISearchbar and the UITableView beneath it to stick to each other. I have tried `self.tableview.origin.y = self.searchbar.origin.y + self.searchbar.frame.height` and the likes but in vain. The tableview just get attached at different y positions when running in different device simulators. I need this done programmatically as I have created the table view that way.

[image]
Image link: https://ibb.co/T8jHLtz

```
func viewDidLoad(){
  recentSearchesTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        recentSearchesTableView.delegate = self
        recentSearchesTableView.dataSource = self
        recentSearchesTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "RecentSearchCell")
        recentSearchesTableView.tag = 202
        recentSearchesTableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        recentSearchesTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Edit: Turns out `recentSearchesTableView.frame.origin.y = searchBar.frame.origin.y + searchBar.frame.height` works perfectly for all devices below iPhone X but the searchbar and tableview overlaps for iPhone X and above :/

Comment: plz add your complete code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add a search bar to a table view is by using `UISearchController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // You may need this for presenting the search controller
    definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
//        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    } else {
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
}
```

This will make managing the logic and display of the search results *much* easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this constraint for searchfield and tableview.

//This will serachfield Top,Leading, Trailing and 50.0 height constraint

```
searchField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
searchField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
searchField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
searchField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
```

//Tableview Top,Leading, Trailing and Bottom constraint

```
tblExpand.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: searchField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

tblExpand.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
tblExpand.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
tblExpand.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: "Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal." It throws this error. @PratikPrajapati

Comment: The searchField.bottomAnchor isn't mentioned. Is that why? @pratik

Comment: is your searchField and tableview is in same view? means have same parent?

Comment: No.I'd forgotten to add the tableView to the parent view. But that doesn't solve the problem. When i use ```recentSearchesTableView.frame.origin.y = searchBar.frame.origin.y + searchBar.frame.height``` it works for all devices below iPhone X but not for iPhone X, XR and above. Overlaps a little on top of one another @pratik

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to do this for the tableView

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        recentSearchesTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.searchField.bottomAnchor),
        recentSearchesTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        recentSearchesTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
        recentSearchesTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```